# Что лучше использовать

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, я начинающий программист и я делаю проект в котором надо решать примеры на время, которое будет уменьшатся, а при правильном ответе он будет прибовлятся и вот я не знаю что лучше всего использовать, для этого. Что вы мне посоветуете?
У меня есть один вариант:
В начале игры создавать int счетчик и запускать Thread с бесконечным цикл и паузой на секунду через TimeUnit. Там же значение будет декрементироваться и отправляться в Handler на установку текста.

И два метода создать plus и minus для +5 и -5 к счетчику. Их вызывать из того места где пример уходит на проверку

Comment: На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов, либо же качественные ответы будут слишком длинными для данного формата. Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов или выделить проблему, ответ на которую будет занимать пару абзацев.

Comment: Вы приложите пару ваших вариантов с набросанными реализациями, а здесь вам уже посоветуют, что быстрее, что лучше, что хуже! И возможно подскажут лучшую альтернативу

Comment: У меня только один вариант есть, как лучше это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с длительностью используйте Date Time API из Java JDK 8.

В частности, вам подойдёт `java.time.Duration`. Класс `Duration` служит для хранения продолжительности времени на основе секунд и наносекунд. Также для отображения длительности можно использовать и другие величины, вроде минут, часов, дней. Однако, основное предназначение этого класса - представление небольших промежутов времени. Для работы с длительными промежутками времени предназначен другой класс - `Period`.

Пример создания:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.JULY, 9, 12, 00);
        LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.JULY, 9, 13, 00);

        Duration duration = Duration.between(from, to);
        System.out.println("duration: " + duration.toMinutes());
    }

}
// output
// duration: 3600000
```

в классе `Duration` существуют удобные методы для изменения продолжительности: `plus*`, `minus*` и `with*`:

```
Метод   Описание
minus(Duration duration)    
minusDays(long daysToSubtract)  
minusHours(long hoursToSubtract)    
minusMinutes(long minutesToSubtract)    
minusSeconds(long secondsToSubtract)    
minusMillis(long millisToSubtract)  
minusNanos(long nanosToSubtract)    
plus(Duration duration) 
plusDays(long daysToAdd)    
plusHours(long hoursToAdd)  
plusMinutes(long minutesToAdd)  
plusSeconds(long secondsToAdd)  
plusMillis(long millisToAdd)    
plusNanos(long nanosToAdd)  
multipliedBy(long multiplicand) 
dividedBy(long divisor) 
withNanos(int nanoOfSecond) 
withSeconds(long seconds)   

import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration
                .parse( "P21DT5H15M45.150S" )
                .plusNanos( 150 )
                .plusDays(2)
                .minusMinutes(15)
                .dividedBy(2);
        System.out.println("duration: " + duration);    
    }
}

// output:
// duration: PT278H30M22.575000075S
```

Неплохой подробный пример, на русском языке, вы можете найти здесь http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2014/07/11/data-i-vremya-v-java-8-prodolzhitelnost-klass-duration.html